# Need help formatting a csv file in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have this snippet of code:

```
import pandas as pd
import os
import numpy as np


df = pd.read_json (r'Desktop\New_folder\responserate_2020.json')
dfcsv = df.to_csv (r'Desktop\New_folder\responserate_2020.csv', index = None)
dfcsv = dfcsv.rename(columns = {'NAME':'name1', 'state':'STATE'}, inplace = False)
```

And I know that in this snippet I am going from a json to csv. I am trying to rename the Column names and I have tried

```
df = df.rename(columns={'oldName1': 'newName1', 'oldName2': 'newName2'})
```

```
df.rename(columns={'oldName1': 'newName1', 'oldName2': 'newName2'}, inplace=True)
```

and none of this seems to work for me.

Also when I print the CSV file. it looks like:

```
                                                        0                     1       2       3           4       5       6      7       8       9
0                                                    NAME                GEO_ID  DRRALL  CRRINT   RESP_DATE  CRRALL  DRRINT  state  county   tract
1          Census Tract 9505.02, Genesee County, New York  1400000US36037950502     0.4    57.5  2020-09-30    74.2     0.4     36     037  950502
2             Census Tract 9506, Genesee County, New York  1400000US36037950600     0.4    50.1  2020-09-30    68.4     0.1     36     037  950600
3             Census Tract 9507, Genesee County, New York  1400000US36037950700     0.0    42.7  2020-09-30    53.7     0.0     36     037  950700
4             Census Tract 9508, Genesee County, New York  1400000US36037950800     0.0    48.2  2020-09-30    60.6     0.0     36     037  950800
```

How would I get rid of the first row of numbers and the first col of numbers?
Would I have to turn the csv into a dataframe? How would I do that? I know that you can go from df to csv but not sure how to do it the other way.

Sorry for the long post, I need to get rid of the first row of numbers and the first col of numbers and rename some of the headers. If possible. I'm kind of new to all of this.

Comment: I typically use `np.savetxt(filename,nparray,delimiter=',')` to output csv files. That may work better for you.

Answer (score 0):

To relabel columns

```py
df.columns = ['col1', 'col2','col3']
```

To skip rows when doing pd.read_csv()

```py
df = pd.read_csv(filepath, skiprows=2)
```

Comment: Thank you So much. df = pd.read_csv(filepath, skiprows=2) works but I am still unable to rename the cols :/

Comment: if you are trying `df.columns` you need to make sure to pass a list of column names which is the same shape as your dataframe.
`df.shape()` will give you the shape of your dataframe.

`df.columns = ['NAME', 'GEO_ID', 'DRRALL', 'CRRINT', 'RESP_DATE', 'CRRALL', 'DRRINT', 'state', 'county', 'tract']`

check out the pandas documentation.
`df.rename` should also work